# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fiftyone.zoo';

Tags: python, dataset, fiftyone

```
'import fiftyone'
import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz

dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset("quickstart")
session = fo.launch_app(dataset)
```

> i tried to install zoo and fiftyone.zoo and install just fiftyone and i upgrade pip and i install it from pycharm interpreter but it gave me the same error massage

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify, you can install FiftyOne and all subpackages like so:

```
pip install fiftyone
```

The [install docs](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/getting_started/install.html) have some troubleshooting tips if there is actually an install issue.

However, I suspect you have a folder named `fiftyone/` or script named `fiftyone.py` in your current working directory. This would confuse Python and cause the wrong thing to be imported when you `import fiftyone`.

Try deleting those or moving to a different directory. Then `import fiftyone.zoo` should work.

Comment: My problem was indeed that I had a filename called `fiftyone.py` in my folder, which I created manually to try it with some snippets.